# Spring MVC 4.3.3 buster cache strategy do not working

Tags: spring-mvc, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying implement a cache buster strategy with Spring MVC v.4.3.3-RELEASE but doesn't work...
In my project i have following assets folder structure

`webapp
└───assets
│   └───css
│   └───img
│   └───js
|       └───app-crm
│       │   customer.js
│       │   ...
└───public
    │   foo
    │   ...`

In my xml config i register o path to assets and the type of version strategy:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/assets/">
    <resource-chain resource-cache="true" auto-registration="true">
        <resolvers>
            <version-resolver>
                <content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/> 
            </version-resolver>
        </resolvers>
    </resource-chain>
</resources>
```

I add in web.xml Url encoding filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- Ensure that you map it to the DispatcherServlet -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And finally i import my static files by example a *.js file:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/js/app-crm/" var="url"></spring:url>
<script src="${url}/customer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when i inspect my web page the file not change! As below...

[image]

Can someone point me to failure?

Comment: Not sure why you expected the filter to solve this?  The filter applies to request urls that have already been sent by the browser, but caching happens on the browser.  Are you familiar with the details of how HTTP caching works?  if not, https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Tanks for share the link @Taylor. Browsers typically cache static resources like javascript, css and image files. This is good as your app loads faster after the initial download of such resources. The next time around, if the resources have not changed, then the browser just fetches these from the cache. 

Problems arise when you release the next version of your web application and the javascript, css or image files have changed. The browser will tend to get the files from it's own cache.

Comment: I'm just trying to preventing browser caching with Spring

Comment: Look at https://www.isostech.com/blogs/software-development/angry-cache-busting-spring-mvc/ or http://thespringthing.blogspot.ca/2015/06/etags-and-browser-cache.html